how does gclb learns where istio ingress gateway is located , which node
I was going through how traffic flows from interent to application when working with istio , in that they used gclb as loadbalancer , I wanted to know how gclb knows which node or in general any loadbalancer knows where the ingress gatweway is located in which node to send traffic over there , does it send to evrynode? or to a single node and then ip routing takes place or it sends to some random node and then routing takes place ?
also if there is any resource where i can clarify this , please attach
I have gone through many articles , but no one has explained this in depth , also I am not looking for cloud native loadbalancing / NEG , I want to know apart from that ho wit works
